# routes.rb no matching route with composite_primary_keys in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a legacy database with a composite primary key.   I have successfully added the composite_primary_keys gem to the project, and can retrieve, and create new records for the object in question.  The operations to update, delete or show a single record are not working, and failing with an error of 
'No route matches [GET] "/estimates/4.0,Test,A,0.0'

The class is defined as:

```
class Estimate < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'estimate'
  self.primary_keys = [:es_gsu_id, :es_loc_name, es_blh_flag, :es_version_id]
end
```

And the routes.rb has been modified with:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints(:id => /\w+(,\w+)*/) do
    resources :estimates
  end

  resources :estimates
end
```

Which I thought for Rails 4 would have it configured correctly.   I can retrieve all and create new as noted, but the single access which actually relies on specifying the PK fields is failing on the routing.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or what I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same problem and after lots of tests found the following solution:

First of all, since you are deviating from default 'id' primary key  assigned by Rails, you need to add this to your routes.rb:

```
resources :estimates, param: :es_gsu_id
```

Just mentioning one of the attributes of your composite key in 'param' hash will do.

Secondly, you don't need this piece of code

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 constraints(:id => /\w+(,\w+)*/) do
   resources :estimates
end
```

Now, your GET request to /estimates/4.0,Test,A,0.0 will be routed to 'show' action of 'estimates' controller where you can retrieve the resource using 'find' method like this:

```
resource ||= Estimate.find(params[:es_gsu_id])
```

params[:es_gsu_id] will have the value '4.0,Test,A,0.0' which will be used by the 'find' method to search for a unique record matching this composite key.